# re string position list builder

Tags: python, regex, string, list, expression

So I have a string like this:

```
'|item1|item2|item3|item4'
```

From that string, I want to build an list like this:

```
['|item1','|item1|item2','|item1|item2|item3','|item1|item2|item3|item4']
```

It essentially looks for each '|' and returns the previous string from that position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a regular expression:

```
stack = []
result = []
for elem in inputstring.split('|'):
    if not elem: continue
    stack.append(elem)
    result.append('|' + '|'.join(stack))
```

which produces:

```
>>> result
['|item1', '|item1|item2', '|item1|item2|item3', '|item1|item2|item3|item4']
```

You could do this with a generator too:

```
def generate_items(inputstring):
    stack = []
    for elem in inputstring.split('|'):
        if not elem: continue
        stack.append(elem)
        yield '|' + '|'.join(stack)

for item in generate_items(inputstring):
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a one list solution to this problem:

```
out = []
for piece in items[1:].split('|'):
    out.append((out[-1] if len(out) else '') + '|' + piece)
```

And if you like generators:

```
def generate_items(inputstring):
    curr = ''
    for item in inputstring[1:].split('|'):
        curr += '|' + item 
        yield curr
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it:

```
list(itertools.accumulate(re.findall('\|\w+', '|item1|item2|item3|item4')))
```